# Xcode 4 project editor causes crash, edit scheme does nothing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, xcode4

I just installed the Xcode 4/iOS SDK 4.3 bundle from the apple dev center. I renamed /Developer to /Developer3 before installing. Anyway, after opening up my 3.x xcode project I wanted to change the target, so I clicked on the project at the top of the left hand side tree, and I got an "Internal Error." (Details, Continue or Crash). So I clicked "Details" and saw:

```
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): -[NSCFDictionary lastObject]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x20102ada0
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: None
```

Earlier I also tried going to "Edit Scheme..." but it just sat there and didn't do anything, like I never clicked the menu item.

Has anyone else seen this or know of a workaround?

Thanks.

**Update:**

So, I uninstalled Xcode 4.0/iOS 4.3 using the uninstall script, then renamed my old Developer3 folder back to Developer and ran that uninstall script... rebooted, re-installed Xcode 4.0/iOS 4.3 and rebooted again, and still am getting the crash. I think it must be something in the project's .plist that I'm trying to open, since I can actually open the project editor with other projects. Hmm.

Comment: Did you reboot after installation?

Comment: Not right away, but then I installed the new Safari and rebooted. Trying again now.

Comment: Just asking because, for example, the documentation says to reboot if you uninstall Xcode before installing a new one. Unsure if just renaming the old Xcode /Developer directory is possibly causing problems.

Comment: Shaggy Frog - reboot is required only if you've installed older version after uninstalling newer one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fixed:**

I had my Info.plist file in my Resources/ directory, so I moved it to the root project folder, and renamed it to AppName-Info.plist and tweaked some stuff in there... for example, hardcoded the Bundle identifier, deleted the old reference to Info.plist in my project file and added the new AppName-Info.plist one. Then, the next time I opened the project, the project editor worked fine. Hopefully that will help someone else in the same boat.